# React Yarn Node Server url setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm using an apache hosting server, when I'm sending this code from react to node, it's working in the localhost, but when I upload to the hosting it's not working.

I have two folder Client for react yarn and Server for Node. I have changed to my domain url and tried but it also didn't work. How to fix to work in both local and in hosting.

```
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3005/send-email', {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using relative paths for your API calls like this:

```
const response = await axios.post('/send-email', {...})
```

Comment: I have tried this relative path '/send-email' but it's not working